# Loop through nested array to return values of object

Tags: javascript

I have a nested array and what I was trying to do was get all the values of the object embedded inside the array. I am currently getting each embedded object and calling `Object.values` to get the values but this method isn't efficient when the array size is big. Is there a way to loop through the array and return the values of each object? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
const data = [{"path":"uploads\\20211115000755-package.json"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115012255-index.html"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115014342-dataServerMid.js"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115031212-index.js"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115031218-uploadDataServer.js"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115031232-index.js"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115031244-dataServerMid.js"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115031250-uploadData.css"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115031303-20211115012255-index.html"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115031318-20211115031303-20211115012255-index.html"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115050204-exportsCapture.JPG"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115052347-[FREE] Stunna 4 Vegas x DaBaby x NLE Choppa Type Beat Call of Duty (320 kbps).mp3"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115200304-Readme.docx"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115202751-Visual Artist Series Fall 2019Corrected.docx"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115203354-ln command examples.docx"},{"path":"uploads\\20211115210027-Q2.docx"},{"path":"uploads\\20211116011817-Fall 2019 ABCD Plattsburgh Syllabi Course Description.docx"}]

//change this to loop and return all the values instead of having to call by index
const dataValues = [Object.values(data[0]).toString(), Object.values(data[1]).toString(), Object.values(data[2]).toString()]

console.log(dataValues)
```

**UPDATE:** I tried @yousaf's method. It worked for my 3 item array but not for this:

```js
const data = [{
  "path": "uploads\\20211115000755-package.json"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115012255-index.html"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115014342-dataServerMid.js"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115031212-index.js"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115031218-uploadDataServer.js"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115031232-index.js"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115031244-dataServerMid.js"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115031250-uploadData.css"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115031303-20211115012255-index.html"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115031318-20211115031303-20211115012255-index.html"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115050204-exportsCapture.JPG"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115052347-[FREE] Stunna 4 Vegas x DaBaby x NLE Choppa Type Beat Call of Duty (320 kbps).mp3"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115200304-Readme.docx"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115202751-Visual Artist Series Fall 2019Corrected.docx"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115203354-ln command examples.docx"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211115210027-Q2.docx"
}, {
  "path": "uploads\\20211116011817-Fall 2019.docx"
}]

//change this to loop and return all the values instead of having to call by index
const dataValues = data.map((obj, idx) => obj["path" + (idx + 1)])

console.log(dataValues)
```

Comment: Use the `map` method: `data.map((obj, idx) => obj["path" + (idx + 1)])`

Comment: @Yousaf take a look at the update code

Comment: In the original code, keys of the objects were like: `path1`, `path2`, etc. In the updated `data` array, key is just `path`. All you need to do is change `obj["path" + (idx + 1)]` to `obj["path"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate over the array, and then push the value to a new array.

```js
const data=[{path1:"uploads\\20211115000755-package.json"},{path2:"uploads\\20211115012255-index.html"},{path3:"uploads\\20211115014342-dataServerMid.js"}];

const arr = [];

for (const obj of data) {
  const [value] = Object.values(obj);
  arr.push(value);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Or you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters).

```js
const data=[{path1:"uploads\\20211115000755-package.json"},{path2:"uploads\\20211115012255-index.html"},{path3:"uploads\\20211115014342-dataServerMid.js"}];

const arr = data.map(obj => {
  const [value] = Object.values(obj);
  return value;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for loop for iterate `data`

```js
const data = [{
  "path1": "uploads\\20211115000755-package.json"
}, {
  "path2": "uploads\\20211115012255-index.html"
}, {
  "path3": "uploads\\20211115014342-dataServerMid.js"
}]

const dataValues = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    dataValues.push(Object.values(data[i]).toString())
}

console.log(dataValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help You. Try it out..

```js
function nestedLoop(obj) {
    const res = {};
    function recurse(obj, current) {
        for (const key in obj) {
            let value = obj[key];
            if(value != undefined) {
                if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                    recurse(value, key);
                } else {
                    // Do your stuff here to var value
                    res[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    recurse(obj);
    return res;
}
```